# Very bad fonts in Evernote

Tags: windows, fonts, evernote, high-dpi

Font renedering is very bad and almost unusable in Evernote in Windows 10 PC. I have a FHD screen and have gdipp installed (disabling that makes no difference).

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after gdipp 0.9.1 installation on Windows 7 x64.

Resolved by installation of older gdipp version 0.7.6 instead of 0.9.1 with Evernote version 5.9.6.9494 (277494) Public.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/475220)

Comment: It works for me, just wanted to share my result, I think it could work for windows 10 as well.